# Could not find class 'com.github.sendgrid.Sendgrid' from method com.example.master.SigupActivity.sendEmail

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sendgrid

I have having in issue in Java eclipse IDE, where I access a function called send() from class com.github.sendgrid.Sendgrid.

I have included all the required jars in the libs folder and added then added the jars to the calsspath.

I get no compile errors, but get Java java.lang.noclassdeffounderror:com.github.sendgrid.

I am using sendgrid api for my android application in Eclipse IDE.

Thank you.

Comment: this is on the debug app right? You have not proguard obfuscated anything yet correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some example code that may help:

https://github.com/thinkingserious/sendgrid-android-example